# Google TensorFlow Object Detection API on Windows - Labelling Images

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I have been using Labellmg to create the xml files in PASCAL VOC format. There is a prebuilt binary version which makes it really easy to start drawing bounding boxes around objects in the images.

https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg

At times, the bounding boxes end up covering unwanted pixels. I am looking for a much more accurate tool on windows which can help me draw polygons or use any sort of point to point tool to annotate the object around the edges. I came across one which can be used on the Mac OS X

https://rectlabel.com/

Also, is it true that Tensorflow object detection API only supports bounding boxes annotations?